# SharePoint Content Template 2013

Tags: content, template

There are different templates which I have created in SharePoint 2013 under content type. I am trying to refer to this templates when I am uploading the documents. I was able to refer to the templates, but the template is not getting applied over the documents.

How to apply the templates over documents while uploding the documents?

Answer (score 1):

Templates are applied to new documents created in the library but not to existing ones that are uploaded.